# Class A declares Class B as a friend, but Class B has Class A as a member

Tags: c++, dependencies, c++14, declaration, definition

So I've got a bit of a chicken-and-egg situation where:

```
class MyWindow;

class MyPanel : public wxPanel
{
public:
    MyPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
    void OnMouseLeftDown(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void OnMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent&);
    void OnMotion(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&);
    void AddPoint(const wxPoint& point);
    void ClearDrawing();
    friend void MyWindow::Submit(wxCommandEvent& event);
private:
    typedef std::vector<wxPoint> Line;
    typedef std::vector<Line> Lines;
    Lines lines;
    wxBitmap bm;

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

class MyWindow : public wxWindow
{
public:
    MyWindow(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
    void Clear(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void Submit(wxCommandEvent& event);
private:
    MyPanel canvas;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

Where I would like `MyPanel` to have `MyWindow::Submit()` be a friend, but also, `MyWindow` has `MyPanel` as a class member, so no matter which I put before the other, or which I forward-declare, I get some error. The code in its current state above leads to the following error:

```
C2027   use of undefined type 'MyWindow'
```

The window is a parent window to the panel, but the panel maintains its own bitmap, and the window needs access to this bitmap for event-handling purposes.

This feels like a pretty hairy problem, the solution to which can probably be only found in the Standard. So that I don't have to spend 300 dollars on the standard, or perhaps several hours leafing through to find exactly this issue, could I get a consultation on how to most elegantly handle this? My language standard is C++14.

Comment: "_So that I don't have to spend 300 dollars on the standard_": Basically nobody actually does that. The draft links at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links are more than enough.

Comment: For the actual problem: From an abstract perspective, why should only one member function be a friend? Shouldn't the whole class be a `friend`? Friending individual member functions is not something I commonly see.

Comment: Sounds like a non-issue or a contrived one - See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Side note: There's nothing elegant in the Standard that will help you with this problem.

Comment: This is an unsolvable circular dependency. You will need to change something in the design of these classes, and/or methods, in order to eliminate the circular dependency. No solution can be given without establishing the actual reason for the circular dependency -- why, specifically, the friend declaration is needed.

Comment: This example strikes me as contrived.   Do one of (1) declare the class `MyWindow` as a `friend` (not just one of its member functions)  (2) change class `MyWindow` so it contains a `MyPanel *`  (and provide constructors to create/manage an instance of `MyPanel` for that pointer to point at) or (3)  Provide public member functions of `MyPanel` that (member functions of ) `MyWindow` can use to do whatever is required.

Comment: *"and the window needs access to this bitmap for event-handling purposes."* -- Why can this access not be given to everyone via a public function? If the bitmap needs to be updated (not just read), why can the window not simply tell the panel that the event happened and let the panel update its bitmap? Event propagation is fairly common.